# discord bot missing 1 required keyword-only argument?

Tags: discord.py, youtube-dl, yt-dlp

for some reason , the bot does not see the **query** argument , although in theory it is passed from the list
ps:im making a music bot
error:

> File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Bot\Mbot\Bot.py", line 77, in play
> await play_music(last_item)
>
> > ```
> >      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> > ```
>
> TypeError: play_music() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'query'

it should work according to the idea like this, I write the play command (link) this link is added to the list for further interaction, and the same link is used to play music, but for some reason the bot does not see the link that I send

im trying replaced **last_item** with **query** and still the bot gives the same error

code:

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ui import Button,View
from discord.utils import get
import yt_dlp
import youtube_dl

intents = discord.Intents().all()
intents.message_content = True
intents.voice_states = True
intents.presences = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!!', intents=intents)


queue_list = []

async def play_music(ctx, *, query):
        ydl_opts = {
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'postprocessors': [{
                'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                'preferredquality': '192',
            }],
        }
        ffmpeg_options = {
            'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
            'options': '-vn',
        }
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(query, download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
        
            voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url2, **ffmpeg_options))
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()

@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, *, query):
    queue_list.append(query)
    last_item = queue_list[-1]
    voice_client = ctx.voice_client
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if voice_channel is None:
        await ctx.send("text1")
    elif 'youtube.com' in query or 'youtu.be' in query:
        await play_music(last_item) 
    else:
        await ctx.send('text2')

bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `play_music(ctx, *, query)` takes two arguments: `ctx`, and `query`, which is a keyword-only argument; that means that you must type in the name of the argument before the actual value, like so: `func(argument_name='whatever')`.

Yet you only inputted a single argument (`await play_music(last_item)`). You should add another argument when calling the function...

...However, the argument `ctx` is unused in `play_music`, so you should just remove the argument `ctx`, and also make `query` non-keyword-only (by removing the asterisk), then you wouldn't need to modify the part where you call the function.